# Shortcuts to type arrows in Vim-LatexSuite

Tags: arrows, vim-latex

I have just learnt vim and Latex-Suite and I really like typing Latex by this program. But I wonder if there are shortcuts to type some arrows  such as `\hookrightarrow` or `\Leftrightarrow` in Vim Latex-Suite? Or are there any ways to type such arrows quickly in Vim Latex-Suite?

I found that there aren't shortcuts for arrows in Tex_Math menu in Gvim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply put

```
\let\hra\hookrightarrow    
\let\lra\leftrightarrow
```

in your preamble, along with any other abbreviations you like.